# Django caches login/logout responses

Tags: django

I have this strange behaviour on a Django based application:

1. after login, the user is redirected to login page again
2. after logout, the user is redirected to login page (correct) but its session is not deleted

Can it be a cache problem?

Both are POST requests, so they should never be cached!

Comment: Show us the login/logout code you've written.

Comment: They are basically Django original methods. I'm checking for the overhead...

Comment: If you are not doing anything suspicious then Django original methods work just fine.

Comment: May it be some proxy server between Django and the client?

Comment: Provide detail info of response headers could be helpful

Comment: @Don Unlikely. But as okm said: provide details of response.